# React JS Page Unresponsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React Js Project. I tested all of the current functionalities and everything worked as expected.

I proceeded to work on some styling aspects before continuing with the functionality and noticed that my webpage wouldn't update. For example, I would just change a `background-color` or some other style prop to something obnoxious and noticeable to see if it would update. It wouldn't.

I was also unable to do anything with the URL. For example, if I was on `http://localhost:3000/messages` and I tried to delete the `/messages` aspect of the url, the page gets stuck loading infinitely.

I also utilize a local token in the local storage, and I suddenly found myself unable to delete it. When I close the window it informs me that the page has become unresponsive. When its in this state also, I am unable to click on anything. I know this to be true because I have a side nav component that works everywhere but once the app freezes like this it doesn't function.

Before continuing it is imperative to note that this error exists on **my machine** only. It still works on anyone else's machine if they have access to the codebase.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? I don't even know what code to show you because this error seemingly came out of nowhere.

Now whenever I run `npm start` to start it, it brings me to the local host, but nothing renders at all. No token, no console statements at all, no ability top refresh or type in the URL. I tried downgrading `react-scripts` to 3.4.4 but that threw a whole slew of other errors.

And before someone suggests that there's an infinite loop somewhere I can promise you there isn't

If anyone even has an idea what could be going on-- something with PIDs or the kernel or the OS or something that would be help, I truly have absolutely no idea what to even look up for help on this and everyone at my office has hit a wall with this

Comment: Are you using a live build? Did you restart the build?

Comment: Yeah, Im using node and totally deleted the `node_modules` file and ran `npm i` again. Actually might have made things worse somehow

Comment: Then my only advice is to try and step backwards. Hopefully you subscribe to the "commit early, commit often" revision tracking philosophy.

Comment: Unfortunately that's still not helping me. I stashed all changes and am still facing the same issue]

Comment: If anyone even has an idea what could be going on-- something with PIDs or the kernal or the OS or something that would be help, I truly have absolutely no idea what to even look up for help on this and everyone at my office has hit a wall with this

Comment: From there I'd start removing components. Eventually it should fire up again.  You can manually delete local storage items.

Comment: I was working in a repo named `messaging` only. Deleted that entirely and still facing the same issues. Rolled back to the version of it we had last week, yet the issue persists